# Mysql Left Join on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables as below:
User table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)      
);
```

And another table as uep which as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `uep` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email_template_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `send_email` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
);
```

I want to get all records from user table and do `left` join to `uep` table only when
`user.id = uep.user_id AND uep.send_email = 0`

but when i run query

```
Select id, group_concat(email_template_id) as T from user
LEFT join uep ON (user.id = uep.user_id AND uep.send_email = 0)
group by user_id limit 100
```

It ignore user from user table which are having send_email = 1.

I want to join uep table only when user.id and send_email =0 else it should be not join and return only user details.

Sql Fiddle :http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f083/2

Any help appricated!!

Comment: Is user a reserved word in mysql? It is in TSQL and this would not work in SQL Server, when you would use ...as T from [user]... instead

Comment: @DanielDyson: `user` is not a reserve keyword.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Please, provide a table with desired result. I don't understand, what you want to get.

Comment: You say uep.send_email = 0 but then you complain that ignores users where uep.send_email = 1.Clarify.

Comment: no send_email field in user table in fiddle

Comment: updated fiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abda99/2
The out put of query in fiddle include user.id 41 which exclude in my workbench. That is what i want.STRANGE

Comment: It doesn't ignore users where send_mail = 1. What it does is return them but with the field T set to NULL. I have added a row to your SQL fiddle to demonstrate this.

Comment: @Mihai:  I want to join `uep` table only when user.id and send_email =0 else it should be not join and return only user details.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Select 
    id, group_concat(email_template_id) as T 
from 
    user
LEFT join 
    uep 
ON 
  (user.id = uep.user_id AND uep.send_email = 0)
OR
  (uep.send_email = 1 AND user.id = uep.user_id)
group by 
  user_id 
limit 
  100;
```

demo at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c28ee/1

Comment: worth noting that whilst this works you should be wary of doing so because it can be a very slow query because of the resulting sub optimum table scans. You should consider using IF within the join condition instead - http://www.wandi-studio.com/Laboratory/Entry/Item/mysql_optimizations___left_join_with_several_%22or%22_conditions-16.sls

Answer (score 1):

your query return wrong result because of "group by" condition. Just change group by user_id to id as mentioned below:

```
Select id, group_concat(email_template_id) as T from user
LEFT join uep ON (user.id = uep.user_id AND uep.send_email = 0)
group by id limit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your post it ignores users with send_email = 1.  It should have them since user is the LEFT-basis of the join, however, it's "T" value would be blank as your LEFT-JOIN only cares about 0 values.  So, what DO you want... two columns?  One where send email = 0, and another where send email = 1?

```
Select 
      u.id, 
      COALESCE( UEP0.T, '' ) T,
      COALESCE( UEP1.T, '' ) T1
   from 
      user u
         LEFT join ( select uep.user_id,
                            group_concat( uep.email_template_id ) as T
                        from
                           uep
                        where
                           uep.send_email = 0
                        group by
                           uep.user_id ) UEP0
            ON (u.id = UEP0.user_id)
         LEFT join ( select uep.user_id,
                            group_concat( uep.email_template_id ) as T
                        from
                           uep
                        where
                           uep.send_email = 1
                        group by
                           uep.user_id ) UEP1
            ON (u.id = UEP1.user_id)
   limit 
      100
```

This version gets BOTH versions...  The left-joins are separately to the UEP table doing their own group concat() for respective send_email status of 0 or 1.  So the user table joins to BOTH results and gets either version, now you can do what you want with the respective template IDs.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to include it in the ON clause. You can simply add a WHERE clause:

```
Select id, group_concat(email_template_id) as T from user
LEFT join uep ON (user.id = uep.user_id)
WHERE uep.send_email = 0
group by user_id limit 100
```

Comment: than it will ignore user having send_email = 1.

Comment: Can you please explain that? `User` table only has `id` and `name` columns. I don't see any `send_email` column.

Comment: This is effectively an INNER JOIN. Any row from user which does not have a matching row from uep will have NULL in uep.send_email, and so be discarded by the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Kickstart: yes. I want to join uep table only when user.id and send_email =0 else it should be not join and return only user details.

Comment: In which case your existing SQL works. The suggestion here by Andrei would only return users with a send_email of 0, any others would be ignored as it is effectively doing an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry don';t have time now to do fiddle, but something like this should work for you.

```
Select id, u2.T from user
LEFT join 
( Select `user_id`, group_concat(email_template_id) as T 
  From uep
  Where uep.send_email = 0
) u2
On user.id = u2.user_id 
group by user_id limit 100
```